# Can anyone tell the me difference between Ubuntu server and lamp stack or server?

Tags: networking, lamp, ubuntu-server

I know that Ubuntu server is for server and LAMP is software for server which stands for Linux Apache MySQL PHP. My doubts are for when it comes to hosting a site. Is it required to install LAMP on Ubuntu server? Or does Ubuntu server has all the features of lamp?

Answer (score 1):

You would normally install Ubuntu(or whatever distro) then all the components of lamp. The server distribution of Ubuntu doesn't include Apache, PHP, or MySQL by default. You can install them with 
`sudo apt install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 apache2 mysql-server`

See this page for more details on the configuration.
https://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies